# How to style list items according to their order

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a menu made of an li list. Each li item needs to have a different background color, according to its position in the list:

The first item is pink,
the second is orange,
the third is green,
and so on...

[image]

Each item has its own ID, so it's supposedly no problem to give each a CSS style of its own. (For example, the first item's ID is menu-item-30, the second item's ID is menu-item-57, and so on, with random numbers as their IDs.)

However, the site is supposed to operate in different languages, and in each of those languages the list items have different IDs. (For example, the item with ID menu-item-30 in the English menu, has ID menu-item-241 in the French menu.)

I'm wondering if the only way to accomplish this is by adding the IDs to the CSS rules, like so:

```
#header #access li.menu-item-30,
#header #access li.menu-item-210, /*spanish*/
#header #access li.menu-item-241 /*french*/{
/*add header prefix to li's only'*/
   background: url('images/headers/navbar.png') 0 -124px repeat-x transparent;
   border-bottom: 3px solid #f26122;
```

}

Or if there is a way - **that will work in IE7 and up** - to use a more general rule, such as nth-child or such.

Comment: "that will work in IE7 and up" and "nth-child" in the same sentence...?

Comment: @BoltClock I wrote "nth-child" as an example for a general rule. That's why I also added _"such as"_. But if that addition only causes confusion, then I'll remove it

Comment: Not confusion, just empathy mixed with pity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one way. You can append `rel="home"` attribute for element and then with css you will be able do that: `#header #access li a[rel="home"] { }`

If you don't have access to the code, then the only way is to write css for each element.

Comment: Thanks. That might help for the `<a>`, but what about styling the `li`?

Comment: Then you append to li rel data not to a and use as this:
`#header #access li[rel="home"] {}
#header #access li[rel="home"] a {}`

Comment: Your answer gave me an easier ides - I just added a class to each li, according to its position/order in the list: menu-item-1, menu-item-2. etc. Thank a lot!